# Assigning a Custom Completed Date for WooCommerce Orders

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'd like to add a custom Completed date to WooCommerce orders, so that if an order is completed on the 01.07 I can change that programatically and set it to a different date.

How is that possible?

I tried adding the following code snippet to my WP site but it's not working as expected: [https://pastebin.com/igUwkbyM](https://stackoverflow.com)

Comment: Please directly paste code into the question and use the formatting tools to format it as code. If you struggle: [How To: Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Welcome to StackOverflow!